# C# Show Form1 on keydown

Tags: c#

How to call Form1.show(); via keydown
Something like this

```
           message msg= new message();

 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            msg.Show();
        }
    }
```

but this not working for me.

Comment: Form1 looks like it's showing already.

Comment: IF form1 isn't created, or not shown or doesn't has the focus it can't receive any key event, you need a global keyboard hook or receive it via the focused form.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is true, but you should set `KeyPreview` property of your  `Form1` to `true` to raise `KeyDown` event

Comment: Please try this first before you post, you'll learn something new.

Comment: I have tried and I use this everytime. Did you try?

Comment: Yes I did.  You did not.  The Enter key is special, like Escape and the cursor keys.  KeyPreview is a VB6 compatibility property, it did not intercept the navigation keys.  Consider proposing to use the form's AcceptButton property or to override ProcessCmdKey().

Comment: Thank you Hans for info, it was useful for me, if this won't solve Leo's problem I will delete my answer. Let's ask to Leo for more info

Comment: Downvoted afte OP solved problem with this,  who and why ) ?